# Jupyter notebook get's end of line removed in Pycharm

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pycharm, formatter, linefeed

On any save, despite all on save formatting being turn off, PyCharm removes the newline at EoF for Jupyter Notebooks. I've tried the Ensure Newline on all files is turned on. I've even tried using `.editorconfig`, but no matter what I do the newline gets removed constantly.

This makes my `git staging` dirty, making all things git difficult.